# D3 linkText appends instead updating existing value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Recently I migrated my graph to v6 where I replaced the `enter()`, `remove()`, `exit()` pattern with `join()`. Unfortunately, I can´t change the link text any longer. Usually, the text should switch between "blue" and "green" as soon as a link was clicked.

I know, that I append a new text object instead of updating the existing value. Which is the problem. It's visible in the browser inspector. But I can´t figure out how to adapt the code, as `join()` is not working at this point.

Any hints?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3 JOIN Test</title>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- import multiselection framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .canvas {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }

    .link {
        cursor: pointer;
        stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        stroke-width: 4px;
    }

    .link:hover {
        stroke: red;
    }

</style>

<body>

    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": 1,
                    "target": 2,
                    "type": "blue"
                },
                {
                    "source": 2,
                    "target": 3,
                    "type": "blue"
                },
                {
                    "source": 3,
                    "target": 1,
                    "type": "blue"
                }
            ]
        }


        // declare initial variables
        var svg = d3.select("svg")
        width = window.innerWidth
        height = window.innerHeight

        // define cavnas area to draw everything
        svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        // remove zoom on dblclick listener
        d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

        var linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linksContainer")
        var nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

        // iniital force simulation
        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            }).distance(200))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("attraceForce", d3.forceManyBody().strength(70));

        initialze()


        function initialze() {
            links = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .on("click", click)

            linkPaths = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("path")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attrs({
                    "class": "linkPath",
                    "fill-opacity": 1,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1,
                    "id": function (d, i) { return "linkPath" + i }
                })
                .style("display", "block")

            linkLabels = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkLabel")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("text")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attrs({
                    "class": "linkLabel",
                    "id": function (d, i) { return "linkLabel" + i },
                    "font-size": 16,
                    "fill": "black"
                })
                .style("display", "block")

            linkLabels
                .append("textPath")
                .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#linkPath' + i })
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .text(function (d) { return d.type })

            nodes = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
                .join("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 30)
                .attr("fill", "whitesmoke")
                .attr("stroke", "white")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)
        }


        function mouseEnter(event, d) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", "lightblue")
        }


        function mouseLeave(event, d) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", "whitesmoke")
        }


        function click(event, d) {
            if (d.type == "blue") {
                d.type = "green"
            } else if (d.type == "green") {
                d.tyoe = "blue"
            }

            initialze()
        }

        function close() {
            contextMenuLink.classList.remove("active")
        }

        function ticked() {
            links
                .attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            nodes
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });

            linkPaths.attr('d', function (d) {
                return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
            });

            linkLabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
                if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
                    var bbox = this.getBBox();

                    rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                    ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                    return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
                }
                else {
                    return 'rotate(0)';
                }
            });
        }


        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }


        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }


        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who face a similar problem. I played around a bit and got it done by adding an empty .text("") attribute to the ".linklabel" class. The correct version looks liks:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3 JOIN Test</title>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .canvas {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }

    .link {
        cursor: pointer;
        stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        stroke-width: 4px;
    }

    .link:hover {
        stroke: red;
    }

</style>

<body>

    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": 1,
                    "target": 2,
                    "type": "blue"
                },
                {
                    "source": 2,
                    "target": 3,
                    "type": "blue"
                },
                {
                    "source": 3,
                    "target": 1,
                    "type": "blue"
                }
            ]
        }


        // declare initial variables
        var svg = d3.select("svg")
        width = window.innerWidth
        height = window.innerHeight

        // define cavnas area to draw everything
        svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        // remove zoom on dblclick listener
        d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

        var linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linksContainer")
        var nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

        // iniital force simulation
        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            }).distance(200))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("attraceForce", d3.forceManyBody().strength(70));

        initialze()


        function initialze() {
            links = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .on("click", click)

            linkPaths = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("path")
                .attr("class", "linkPath")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkPath" + i })

            linkLabels = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkLabel")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("text")
                .attr("class", "linkLabel")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkLabel" + i })
                .attr("font-size", 16)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text("")
                
            linkLabels
                .append("textPath")
                .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#linkPath' + i })
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .text(function (d) { return d.type })

            nodes = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
                .join("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 30)
                .attr("fill", "whitesmoke")
                .attr("stroke", "white")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)
        }

        function click(event, d) {
            if (d.type == "blue") {
                d.type = "green"
            } else if (d.type == "green") {
                d.type = "blue"
            }

            initialze()
        }


        function ticked() {
            links
                .attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            nodes
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });

            linkPaths.attr('d', function (d) {
                return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
            });

            linkLabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
                if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
                    var bbox = this.getBBox();

                    rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                    ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                    return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
                }
                else {
                    return 'rotate(0)';
                }
            });
        }


        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }


        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }


        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```